# Pulling Zillow Rent Data from Zillow API

Tags: python, api, zillow

I am playing around with the Zillow API, but I am having trouble retrieving the rent data. Currently I am using a Python Zillow wrapper, but I am not sure if it works for pulling the rent data.

This is the help page I am using for the Zillow API:
https://www.zillow.com/howto/api/GetSearchResults.htm

```
import pyzillow
from pyzillow.pyzillow import ZillowWrapper, GetDeepSearchResults
import pandas as pd

house = pd.read_excel('Housing_Output.xlsx')


### Login to Zillow API
address = ['123 Test Street City, State Abbreviation'] # Fill this in with an address
zip_code = ['zip code'] # fill this in with a zip code

zillow_data = ZillowWrapper(API KEY)
deep_search_response = zillow_data.get_deep_search_results(address, zip_code)
result = GetDeepSearchResults(deep_search_response)

# These API calls work, but I am not sure how to retrieve the rent data
print(result.zestimate_amount)
print(result.tax_value)
```

---

**ADDING ADDITIONAL INFO:**

Chapter 2 talks how to pull rent data by creating a XML function called zillowProperty. My skills going into XML aren't great, but I think I need to either:

a) import some xml package to help read it
b) save the code as an XML file and use the open function to read the file

https://www.amherst.edu/system/files/media/Comprehensive_Evaluation_-_Ningyue_Christina_Wang.pdf

I am trying to provide the code in here, but it won't let me break to the next line for some reason.

Comment: Please use `dir(result)` to see all methods that are available inside the `result`. Does it contain anything related to rent?

Comment: @FatihAkici, no I don't see anything related to rent when I use `dir(result)`.

Comment: Can you please fill out the address and zip_code fields so I can reproduce what you have and help you?

Comment: @FatihAkici, I filled in a test address and zip_code. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can see that rent is not a field one can get using the `pyzillow` package, by looking into the attributes of your `result` by running `dir(result)`, as well as the code here: [Pyzillow source code](https://github.com/hanneshapke/pyzillow/blob/master/pyzillow).

However, thanks to the beauty of open source, you can **edit the source code** of this package and get the functionality you are looking for. Here is how:

First, locate where the code sits in your hard drive. Import `pyzillow`, and run:

```
pyzillow?
```

The `File` field shows this for me:

```
c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzillow\__init__.py
```

Hence go to `c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzillow` (or whatever it shows for you) and open the `pyzillow.py` file with a text editor.

Now we need to do two changes.

**One:** Inside the `get_deep_search_results` function, you'll see `params`. We need to edit that to turn the `rentzestimate` feature on. So change that function to:

```
def get_deep_search_results(self, address, zipcode):
    """
    GetDeepSearchResults API
    """

    url = 'http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetDeepSearchResults.htm'
    params = {
        'address': address,
        'citystatezip': zipcode,
        'zws-id': self.api_key,
        'rentzestimate': True # This is the only line we add
    }
    return self.get_data(url, params)
```

**Two:** Go to `class GetDeepSearchResults(ZillowResults)`, and add the following into the `attribute_mapping` dictionary:

```
'rentzestimate_amount': 'result/rentzestimate/amount'
```

**Voila!** The customized&updated Python package now returns the Rent Zestimate! Let's try:

```
from pyzillow.pyzillow import ZillowWrapper, GetDeepSearchResults

address = ['11 Avenue B, Johnson City, NY']
zip_code = ['13790']

zillow_data = ZillowWrapper('X1-ZWz1835knufc3v_38l6u')
deep_search_response = zillow_data.get_deep_search_results(address, zip_code)
result = GetDeepSearchResults(deep_search_response)

print(result.rentzestimate_amount)
```

Which correctly returns the Rent Zestimate of $1200, which can be validated at [the Zillow page of that address](https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/11-Avenue-B-Johnson-City-NY-13790/29756025_zpid/).

Comment: It won't let me upvote your answer because I still have under 15 reputation points, but this worked! Great use of out of the box thinking skills!!!

Comment: Glad I was able to help, @BobbyZeydelis. Thanks for the kind words!

Comment: Thanks, @grantog! Glad it helped.