# Pulling Zillow Mortgage Data from Zillow API

Tags: python, python-3.x, zillow

I am attempting to pull the 'Monthly Cost' section of the housing listing from Zillow. Essentially, I need to have the cost of the mortgage, HOA(if available) and property taxes. (see this link: https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/181-Willow-St-Johnson-City-NY-13790/29756925_zpid/)

I have been using a Python wrapper, but the wrapper seems to only incorporate a few parameters. I was having another issue where I couldn't pull rent data and the solution was that I needed to add the actual parameter into the zillow api package. (See this link to that Stackoverflow issue: [Pulling Zillow Rent Data from Zillow API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56993325/pulling-zillow-rent-data-from-zillow-api/56999890?noredirect=1#comment100558752_56999890))

I have also found this resource from Zillow that I think is the key to me getting mortgage data:

Homepage of Zillow's mortgage APIs:
https://www.zillow.com/mortgage/api/#/

The API page for getting mortgage rates:
https://mortgageapi.zillow.com/api/getCurrentRates

```
    import pyzillow
from pyzillow.pyzillow import ZillowWrapper, GetDeepSearchResults
import pandas as pd

house = pd.read_excel('Housing_Output.xlsx')


### Login to Zillow API
address = ['123 Test Street City, State Abbreviation'] # Fill this in with an address
zip_code = ['zip code'] # fill this in with a zip code

# API Key needed from Zillow to login
zillow_data = ZillowWrapper(API KEY)

# Access Zillow deep search API
deep_search_response = zillow_data.get_deep_search_results(address, zip_code)
result = GetDeepSearchResults(deep_search_response)


print(result.zestimate_amount)
print(result.tax_value)
```